# How to add an integer number to a specific column in Vim editor?

Tags: visual-block

I'm needing to add 184 to multiple (but not all) columns in Vim editor.  The following command only adds 184 to the very first column, even if the second or the third column is the only highlighted column in visual block mode, only the first column gets added onto.  I can't use `/g` at the end cause there's numbers that I can't add to in each line as well

```
:s/\d\+/\=submatch(0) + 184
```

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) Do you still have something open in your question? Otherwise may be could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

`<c-a>` can be used in Visual Block mode e.g. `<c-v>`.

Lets say you have the following text:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

You can select the 2nd column with `f2<c-v>j` then add your number via `184<c-a>`

Then you will have:

```
1 186 3
1 186 3
```

There are other methods as well. However, I tend to favor shelling out to use `awk`. The following command will add `184` to the 2nd column:

```
awk '$2+=184' input.txt
```

You can do this from Vim with a range and the filter command, `!`. Select you lines visually then run `:!awk '$2+=184'`

For more help see:

```
:h v_CTRL-A
:h :!
:h :range
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to stay in Vim you can do:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V\d\+/\=submatch(0)+184/g
```

Vim is very much line oriented. The range `'<,'>` specify that the substitution should only occur in the line selected.

But the `\%V` only match (with zero width) if the next character is within the selection.